# Unusual clump of small prime numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

\begin{align}
22097 & = 19\times1163 \\
22098 & = 2 \times 3 \times 29 \times 127 \\
22099 & = 7 \times 7 \times 11 \times 41 \\
22100 & = 2 \times2 \times 5 \times5 \times 13 \times 17 \\
22101 & = 3 \times 53 \times 139 \\
22102 & = 2 \times 43 \times 257 \\
22103 & = 23 \times 31 \times 31
\end{align}
Smallest $14$ primes:
$$
\require{cancel}
2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,\xcancel{37},41,43
$$
That all but one of the smallest $14$ primes occur among factorizations of only seven consecutive integers seems unusual. Has anyone ever been precise about the unusualness of this sort of thing?

Comment: That primes up to $7$ occur is obvious. For any larger $p$, the naive probability it occurs somewhere in these factorizations is $7/p$, multiplying that over primes $\leq 43$ gives a chance one in about 220000. That you got all but one by around 22000 sounds very reasonable.

Comment: To be clear, you said the "chance" is $$\frac1{220\,000} = \frac1{22}\times10^{-4} \quad \leftarrow \text{exponent} = -4$$ and I got this by about $$ \frac1{22\,000} = \frac1{22} \times 10^{-3}, \quad \,\,\leftarrow \text{exponent} = -3 $$ the latter being $10$ times the former.

Comment: @Wojowu $\qquad\uparrow\qquad$

Comment: Meanwhile, $714=2\times3\times7\times17$, $715=5\times11\times13$, two consecutive numbers with all of the first seven primes. (Also, $2+3+7+17=5+11+13$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruth%E2%80%93Aaron_pair

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A117581

Comment: Not a mathematician, but these primes all need to be smaller than 148, the square root, and obviously chances a number is divisible by a lower number is higher. Doesn't seem unusual to me. Does this property also hold at extremely large number ranges though?

Comment: @MichaelHardy The chance of 1/220000 is for *all* primes appearing in th factorization. If you were to estmate it for all but one prime, then it should land right in the ballpark of 1 in 10000 or so. And even if it included all the primes in the range, in cases like this, appearing just one order of magnitude early is really not *that* surprising, strong law of small numbers and what not. The asymptotic behavior would even it out.

Comment: @Wojowu : From this probabilistic point of view, what do you think of the sequence $1100$ through $1106$, a sequence of seven consecutive integers in whose prime factorizations all of the ten smallest prime numbers, $2$ through $29,$ appear?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm sure you could just do the math yourself. Works out to [about 1 in 261](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=11%2F7*13%2F7*17%2F7*19%2F7*23%2F7*29%2F7), so the smaller examples Dave mentions below their answer fit right in.

Comment: John Conway used similar ranges (near 150 and 2000) to help factor numbers in his head: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2023/03/03/conway-factoring/

Comment: @aorq : I upvoted your comment. Then not seeing the "1", there, I tried to upvote it again and got an error message saying I had already undone my upvote (although I had not) and cannot upvote it again.

Comment: A slightly related phenomenon is that between the consecutive prime numbers $1327$ and $1361$ (an unusually large gap for numbers that small, since $1361-1327=34$) all of the prime numbers not exceeding the square roots of the numbers in this interval (i.e. all that are${}\le31$) occur as factors. I think only finitely many prime gaps exist about which that can be said, although I don't know how many.

Answer (score 9):

This happens earlier at 18444 to 18450, and again from 21109 to 21115. It doesn't seem very special. If you want 37 as well, try 138411 to 138417.

This seems very much in line with Wojowu's naïve estimate.

Here's a table of the smallest $n$ such that $\prod_{i=0}^{m-1}(n+i)$ is divisble by all the primes up to $p$, where $m$ is given in the top row. I stopped each column when my laptop got bored. Column 2 is A118478.

[image: Table]

Comment: Do you have to go all the way up to $138\,411$ to get all of the first $14$ within an interval of length${}\le7\text{?} \qquad$

Comment: Yes, that's the first one. The next ones start at 264362, 325375, 587075, 589741, 728156.

Comment: Also, note that 138411, 325375, 587075 also cover divisibility by 47, and the last of these, 587075 covers everything up to 53. But if you want to include 59 you have to go all the way up to 95142096.

Comment: Here, the outlier is 587075, which is very small to capture everything up to 53. The 95142096 is almost exactly what Wojowu predicts (his estimate gives about 94.5 million)

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
1100 & = 2\times2\times5\times5\times11 \\
1101 & = 3\times367 \\
1102 & = 2\times19\times29 \\
1103 & = 1103 \\
1104 & = 2\times2\times2\times2\times3\times23 \\
1105 & = 5 \times13\times17 \\
1106 & = 2\times7\times79
\end{align}
$$
The ten smallest primes appear here: $$2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29
$$

Comment: And also 203 to 209. And if you want 31 too, 986 to 992.

Comment: If you want a real outlier, the ten numbers from 774 to 783 contain all primes up to 43 as factors.

Comment: With 43 at the beginning, so 775 to 783 cover all up to 41.